# Prove equality of lists with list_beq

Tags: coq

`list_beq` is generated by `Scheme Equality for list.`.

I'm sure that `l = v` if `list_beq A eq l v` holds and want to prove it.

But, we can't proof that unless `A` and `eq` are not concrete.

So, I want to proof that when `A = nat` `eq = Nat.eqb`.

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations. 
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect.
Scheme Equality for list.

Lemma list_eq (l v:list nat) : list_beq nat Nat.eqb l v = true -> l = v.
Proof.
case: l.
remember (list_beq nat Nat.eqb [] []).
destruct b;last first.
inversion Heqb.
destruct v => //.

intros.
destruct v => //.
rewrite /list_beq in H.
Abort.
```

I don't know how to do any more.

Please tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one reason for/benefit of using Schemes is to *not* have to do the induction and go through all the cases yourself.

If you search for `list_beq` that was generated by `Scheme` you find the generated lemma `internal_list_dec_bl` that can help you to reason about the absurd case you get when reasoning about `list_eq_dec`.

```
Require Import List. Import ListNotations.
Scheme Equality for list.

Lemma list_eq (l v:list nat) : list_beq nat Nat.eqb l v = true -> l = v.
  destruct(list_eq_dec _ PeanoNat.Nat.eqb) with l v as [H|H];
    intros; try apply PeanoNat.Nat.eqb_eq in H. trivial. trivial. trivial.
  exfalso.
  apply H. apply internal_list_dec_bl with Nat.eqb.
  apply PeanoNat.Nat.eqb_eq. apply H0.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have proved on my own.

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List  Coq.Bool.Bool.
Import ListNotations. 
Scheme Equality for list.
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect.

Lemma list_eq (l v:list nat) : list_beq nat Nat.eqb l v = true -> l = v.
Proof.
- elim: l v.
  remember (list_beq nat Nat.eqb [] []).
  destruct b;last first.
  inversion Heqb.
  destruct v => //.
- intros.
  destruct v => //.
  rewrite /= in H0.
  apply andb_true_iff in H0.
  move: H0 => [left right].
  f_equal.
  apply PeanoNat.Nat.eqb_eq in left.
  apply left.
  apply H in right.
  apply right.
Qed.
```